# Dali Commissioning Without Randomise

Tags: dali

I have 2 slave devices connected to my `dali` bus. I can set their `short address` using the below steps:

1. `Terminate`
2. `Initialise`
3. `Randomise`
4. Set `B1`, `B3` and `B5` search addresses
5. `Compare`
6. Go back to step4 until there is only one luminaire
7. `Program` the short address
8. `Withdraw`
9. Go back to step4 until there is no luminaire left

**Q1.** When there is only one slave device in the `dali` bus, I can assign `short addresses` using above steps, one by one. But when there are 2 slave devices in the `dali` bus, I can only assign short address to one of them, the next luminaire does not respond to `compare` commands. Is there any chance it might be related to an electrical issue?

**Q2.** As I understood, if we have only one slave device in the `dali` bus, we can assign it a short address without using `randomise`. I'm following the below steps to achieve this:

1. Broadcast `A3` command with the desired address. e.g. for the short address of `05`, send: `0xA305`
2. Broadcast `CMD128` to make the luminaire use `05` as the short address, send: `0x8180`

But I couldn't set short address using this method. I also tried `Terminate`-`Initialise` before this process but it didn't work either. Am I misunderstanding the `DTR` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using DTR to program a short address, there is a special format. The value needs to be left shifted one place and then the least significant bit set. Command 128 (opcode byte 0x80) STORE DTR AS SHORT ADDRESS gives the bitwise structure of the DTR for this as 0AAA AAA1 where the A bits are bits of the short address, or to clear the short address, use MASK (all bits 1).

In C, this would be written

DTR = (addr << 1) | 0x01;

This is equivalent to multiplying the address by two then adding one. So working backwards from your case of DTR = 0x05, addr is 2.

The DTR is set by sending command 257 (address byte 0xA3). All control gears will set their DTR, this command is not addressed, but Command 128 STORE DTR AS SHORT ADDRESS is addressed, and is a Configuration command so needs to be sent twice within 100ms.

Comment: Did you mean this when we are sending `CMD163` to add something to `DTR`? I couldn't see anything related to this. Anyway, I tried sending `0xA305` then `0x8180` to set the address to `02` as you said. Then tried turning the lamp on using `0x0400` but it didn't work either. I can not get any response to `Query Short Address` or `Query DTR Content`

Comment: Not command 163, that is QUERY POWER ON LEVEL. DTR is set with Command 128. 0x8180 is SET DTR AS SHORT ADDRESS sent to Group 0. Unless you already have set up gear to be in Group 0, this will not do anything, you probably mean 0xFF80 which is the broadcast addressed version. 0x0400 is DAPC Short addr 2, level 0 which is off.

Comment: Thanks Martin, the problem was about broadcasting. I used 0xA305, then 0xFF80 and it worked. I can toggle led using 0x0400 and 0x04FE.